# Org Babel incorrectly displaying Shell output

Tags: org-babel

Org Babel (Shell) in a session ends up truncating output from the shell.

MWE:

`test.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("""
Stats: CPU Busy 24 (100.00%)
Stats: IO Busy  15 (62.50%)

Stats: Total Time Busy 24 (100.00%)
""")
```

`test.org`:

```
#+begin_src shell :session test :results output
./test.py
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
 : 
 : )
 : )
 : )
```

It seems like it ignores everything before `%`, which is rather surprising. I tried removing the `%`, and everything worked fine.

Tested on Emacs 27.1 and Emacs master, Ubuntu Jammy (22.04), using `emacs -q`.

Edit:
Also tested on Termux, Emacs 28.3. Behaviour is replicated. In the process, also found a better MWE

```
#+begin_src shell :session test :results output
echo "Hello world #"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be specifying the name of the shell.

```
#+begin_src bash :session test :results output
echo "Hello world #"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello world #
```